# What are the pros and cons of PHPDesigner and PhpStorm?

Tags: php

What are the pros and cons of PHPDesigner and PhpStorm?

Comment: "Best" is subjective; I tried to make your question a bit more objective. You may want to put more detail into your question if you think it's relevant.

Comment: @icktoofay .... just wanted to know the pros and cons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the meantime, we have introduced PhpStorm (after using Zend Studio, Aptana, Netbeans and Eclipse) and our whole team agrees that it is by far the best IDE we have ever worked with. There is no qustion, PhpStorm is taking the world of PHP by storm.

Contrary to Eclipse based IDEs, PhpStorm is fast, development is fast and supports the new important trends quickly. It already supports things like Phing, SASS, PHP CodeSniffer, Github, etc. out of the box.

---

Old answer:

I can't give you a very fact based long analysis but I'd say PHPDesigner gets nowhere near PHPStorm. Even the PHPDesigner website looks a bit fishy to me. A page full of meaningless/fake awards. The first two persons under testimonials mention 'Dreamweaver' as an IDE :) and the software seems to be developed by only one person. Support for version control is minimal, there is no phpunit integration, etc. phpStorm has all this and doesn't boast with awards and testimonials but has a team behind the development. Should be clear!

Comment: The code the guy is writing in the demo is pretty horrible too, stuff like `nl2br(htmlentities(stripslashes(strip_tags(trim($var)))))` and unescaped SQL query params, and `<center>` tags...

Comment: This is a terrible answer that not only bases its criticisms on random observations and ignorance, but also reads like an advert for PhpStorm ("PhpStorm is taking the world of PHP by storm"). As someone who's actually used PhpDeveloper, I want to add that it's an an excellent IDE. Well supported and frequently updated. It's also the fastest IDE I've ever used. I won't say it's better than PhpStorm, as I've not used it, and I won't criticize it based on its website.

Comment: The problem with PHPStorm is that it's Java based, which means constant lagging even for menu items and lousy font screen rendering. At times I feel like PHPStorm tries to do too much and as a result the performance suffers. PHPDesigner on the other hand is not Java based and the new 8 version has some neath features. I'm not a fan of either, I'm just sharing my 2 cents.

Comment: phpDesigner is still faster than PHPstorm. However, it lacks some important features, lack of integrity of 3rd tools, phpdesigner cant deal with namespaces, traits. It couldve been the number one, but its barely developed

Answer (score 4):

For a while I used PHP Storm as my main IDE on windows until I switched to Ubuntu, it is an awesome IDE and has everything built in and awesome Version Control Integration.

There are a few things I don't like about it:
PHP Storm is a java based IDE, similar to eclipse, this causes it to be a memory hog.
PHP Storm is a java based IDE, although this makes it easier to be cross platform, it also responds badly if your platform (e.g. Ubuntu) is a bit rubbish with Java.

I did use the older version of PHP Designer for a while on windows as well,
This was also a good IDE, although I found the UI to be a bit too disconnected, I also felt like it was an IDE aimed at beginner developers and was a bit basic.

Overall I prefer PHP Storm, although my current IDE of choice is Net Beans, which has the bonus of being free ;)